# React typescript Antd add checkbox to Form.List and set the value to state

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to include checkbox to Form.List as dynamic fields so when click on add button new fields should add to list. But I can not understand how to set the values to state to submit as payload.

Here bellow the code for checkbox as in Form.List

```js
    import { useState } from "react";
    import { Form, Input, Checkbox, Row, Col, Image } from "antd";
    
    type FormData = {
      students: Student[];
    };
    
    type Student = {
      student_name: string;
      passed: boolean;
    };
    
    const MyComponent = () => {
      const [passed, setPassed] = useState<boolean>(true);
    
      const onPassed = (event: any) => {
        setPassed(!passed);
      };
    
      const onSave = (values: FormData) => {
        form.setFields([
          {
            name: "students",
            value: values?.students?.map((student) => ({
              student_name: student.name,
              passed: student.passed,
            })),
          },
        ]);
      };
    
      return (
        <Form onFinish={onSave}>
          <Form.Item>
            <Form.List name="students">
              {(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
                <>
                  {fields.map((field) => (
                    <Form.Item key={`students-${field.key}`}>
                      <Row wrap={false}>
                        <Col md={20}>
                          <Form.Item name={[field.name, "student_name"]}>
                            <Input />
                          </Form.Item>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={3}>
                          <Form.Item name={[field.name, "passed"]}>
                            <Checkbox
                              defaultChecked={setPassed}
                              onChange={onPassed}
                            >
                              Passed
                            </Checkbox>
                          </Form.Item>
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </Form.Item>
                  ))}
                  <Form.Item>
                    <Image onClick={() => add()} src="" />
                  </Form.Item>
                </>
              )}
            </Form.List>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      );
    };
    
    export default MyComponent;
```

I wanted to send data to onSave method when the form should submit and I want achieve the payload should like bellow

```json
"students": [
        {
            "student_name": "sample name",
            "passed": true
        },
        {
            "student_name": "sample name 1",
            "passed": false
        }
     ....
 ],
```

Comment: Well it looks like the value for each `Checkbox` will take the value of `passed` and not the value from the `students` array data. Instead you should set the state for an _index_ of `students`, such that the values are listened to correctly later. You have `defaultChecked` but no `checked` value for each `Checkbox`.